# react-admin: How to overwrite a field's value by code in Edit view?

Tags: react-admin

Can I overwrite a field's value by code, before user can edit it?

I have tried to overwrite record property of xxxInput, but not work -

```
export const PrefillInput = ({ record, children, prefill, ...rest }) => {
return cloneElement(children, {
    record: { ...record, ...prefill },
    ...rest
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I find what's wrong. 
PrefillInput should be applied to Form, not XXXInput.